# How to store strings in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like the user to be able to create a nickname for a string that shows up in their textview. The app will feed a string into the activity through a service and display it in a textview. I would then like the user to be able to nickname that string, so that every time the string is displayed again the nickname will show up instead of the original string.

My question is, can I use shared preferences to do this? What would be the logic behind the user being able to assign nicknames? If you could point out any literature or sample code that would be greatly appreciated as well. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I have read that, and also this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html but I still cannot figure out the logic behind it. Would I just check to see if a string matches something in the shared preferences before I display it to the viewer?

Comment: So, you are now a SharedPreferences expert. It should be easy for you to read and write from a SharedPreference. `At a certain point in your app lifecycle, write a preference using a "name" and a value. Retrieve the value when the app starts and compare it to something. Act consequently.` It couldn't be easier.

Comment: Okay, seems like that is the way to go. Do you want to post up a answer so I can accept it? Or should I post up a solution once I am finished? I'm still new to etiquette here.

Comment: Better to post your solution. It'd be long to convert my comments to a decent answer. You can post your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Okay, sounds good to me.

Comment: OK, you were lazier than me, so I posted my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I worded my question poorly, and now I'm going to have to ask another question for what I really wanted. Your solution works perfectly for what is being asked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorhithm:

- At a certain point in your app lifecycle, write a preference using a "name" and a value.
- Retrieve the value when the app starts and compare it to something.
- Act consequently.

From the reference site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

**Using Shared Preferences**
The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

**User Preferences**
Shared preferences are not strictly for saving "user preferences," such as what ringtone a user has chosen. If you're interested in creating user preferences for your application, see PreferenceActivity, which provides an Activity framework for you to create user preferences, which will be automatically persisted (using shared preferences).

To get a SharedPreferences object for your application, use one of two methods:

- getSharedPreferences() - Use this if you need multiple preferences files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.
- getPreferences() - Use this if you need only one preferences file for your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your Activity, you don't supply a name.

To write values:

- Call edit() to get a SharedPreferences.Editor.
- Add values with methods such as putBoolean() and putString().
- Commit the new values with commit()
- To read values, use SharedPreferences methods such as getBoolean() and getString().

Here is an example that saves a preference for silent keypress mode in a calculator:

```
public class Calc extends Activity
{
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
        super.onCreate(state);
        //...

        // Restore preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
        setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
        // All objects are from android.context.Context
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```